# Stacking images in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I have [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) running with 5 images cycling at a time.

The trouble I'm having is getting 15 images to display on the first slide stacked in a 5 across and 3 down layout so users can scroll/paginate through 15 images at a time rather than just 5.

I'm currently using:

```
var slickOpts = {
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5,
        dots: true,
        prevArrow: '.btn-prev',
        nextArrow: '.btn-next'
    };
```

When I set both `slidesToShow` and `slidesToScroll` to 15 it just fits them all on one row instead of stacking them.

I've also tried increasing the parent container height but still no luck.

```
#dashboard {
    height: 600px
}
```

How can I get them to stack in that 5x3 layout and scroll through 15 at a time?

http://jsfiddle.net/q1qznouw/19/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q1qznouw/31/)**

You can tell the plugin that first 15 items are 1 item this way you can scroll a set of 15 items.

HTML:

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel__item">1</div>
        <div class="panel__item">2</div>
        <div class="panel__item">3</div>
        <div class="panel__item">4</div>
        <div class="panel__item">5</div>
        <div class="panel__item">6</div>
        <div class="panel__item">7</div>
        <div class="panel__item">8</div>
        <div class="panel__item">9</div>
        <div class="panel__item">10</div>
        <div class="panel__item">11</div>
        <div class="panel__item">12</div>
        <div class="panel__item">13</div>
        <div class="panel__item">14</div>
        <div class="panel__item">15</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel__item">16</div>
        <div class="panel__item">17</div>
        <div class="panel__item">18</div>
        <div class="panel__item">19</div>
        <div class="panel__item">20</div>
        <div class="panel__item">21</div>
        <div class="panel__item">22</div>
        <div class="panel__item">23</div>
        <div class="panel__item">24</div>
        <div class="panel__item">25</div>
        <div class="panel__item">26</div>
        <div class="panel__item">27</div>
        <div class="panel__item">28</div>
        <div class="panel__item">29</div>
        <div class="panel__item">30</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (For Layout):

```
.panel__item {
    border: 10px solid #333;
    background: #ccc;
    height:200px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 72px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 16%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel__row {
    margin: 0 -2%;
}
```

Dont forget to change the number of items in JS from 5 to 1.

Comment: Aah, you were faster than me :) +1

Comment: @ImranBughio thank you so much and also to you anspmn. What I liked abut anpsmn's one though is that the responsiveness allowed it to float nicely http://jsfiddle.net/q1qznouw/29/. In yours if you move the window in a bit you'll see the 5th one float to it's own row. Any way to show an example where it flows nicely?

Comment: @ImranBughio You're a champion!! Thank you so much. Answer accepted with pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please check
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/q1qznouw/23/ 
You need to set
    height:200px !important;
     width:200px !important;

 in panel and also need to set **overflow:hidden** to your dashboard and sets its height accordingly

Comment: thank you although the images are not in order :/ can you work out how to get them displaying in order: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and next row 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...